# Get header of existing page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

Is there a way to get the header of the current page in angularjs, without having to do a separate call?  I can't find this in the docs anywhere, but it seems like it should be possible.

E.g. if the file `index.html` contains the angular code, how do I read the header of the initial request to get `index.html`?  I could use `$http` to make the call again, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: You can't access page headers via Javascript, without an ajax request, so you may be able to get the initial route, but not the index.

Comment: Can't really understand your question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NoahMatisoff my angular code is referenced by an html file, which causes the script to be loaded.  How do I get the header for that html file?  For example in chrome debugger I can just click `Network` tab then select the HTML file and view the header.  Is there a way to read this with angular?

Comment: The question for index http headers duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript.

Comment: You are asking to have access to the response header of a http call that has been handled directly from the browser? How do you expect to have access to the request or response of an http call that your code isn't handling?? I mean, with plain JS you can't do that right? Then, what makes you think that you can do that with Angular?

Comment: @Dylan that involves another call to the server, which I would like to avoid if possible

Comment: @Josep what about the header for the JS file itself?  Is that available to the JS?

Comment: @tyler same thing, if you are not handling the http request you won't have access to the request or the response, unless the code that it's making the request exposes that information somehow, which is not the case. So, I'm sorry but the answer is no. However, if I may: what is exactly what you need from the response header? Because there could be other ways to obtain the information of the headers (i.e. cookies)

Comment: @tyler I see, well then I'm sorry that the answer was no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not handling the http request you won't have access to the request or the response, unless the code that it's making the request exposes that information somehow, which is not the case. So, I'm sorry but the answer is no.

However, if I may: what is exactly what you need from the response header? Because there could be other ways to obtain the information of the headers (i.e. cookies)

Comment: The use is for tracking environment variables. We can embed directly onto the page and then just read it, but was trying to go through headers if possible. Cookies are not an option.